# Selenium java code to find number of H2 tag on web page

Tags: java, selenium

Please suggest a code to find total number of H2 tags on a web page.

Below is my code but giving incorrect output

URL to check: http://www.marksandspencer.com/l/lingerie/sexy-lingerie

```
public class H1andh2 {
  WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    public void beforeTest(){
        driver= new FirefoxDriver();
    }


  @Test(priority=2)
  public void pid(){

        driver.get("http://www.marksandspencer.com/l/lingerie/sexy-lingerie");
        List<WebElement> h1= driver.findElements(By.tagName("h1"));
        System.out.println("number of H1 tags are:"+ h1.size());
        List<WebElement> h2= driver.findElements(By.tagName("H2"));
        System.out.println("number of H2 tags are:"+ h2.size());


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `h2` instead of `H2`?

Comment: Yes I tried that only first but still not working. I am getting output as 85 however there is no h2 tag on my page.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the page is not yet fully loaded.  Well it is loaded but JavaScript may still be adding elements.  If the h2 elements are deeply embedded in HTML it might help to find an element higher in the path and then do your findElement for the h2 tags on that intermediate WebElement (shortens the search; you wouldn't want that search to timeout before it reaches the h2 tags).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example code to extract h2 tags using Java:

```
String Tag = "h2"; 
List<WebElement> myTags =  driver.findElements(By.tagName(Tag));
// now extracting the value 
// this for loop will print/extract all the values for tag 'H2'.
for(int l=0;l<myTags.size();l++){
    // extracting tags text
    String value_h2 = myTags.get(l).getText();
    System.out.println(Tag + "is : " + myTags.get(l).getText());
}
```